# Trouble sending a get request with a header in the requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to query from an API, but it says that I need to include an API key in the request header, but the requests library only supports dictionaries for headers, and I need to include only the API key or else it will give me a 401 error. Is there any other way to do this?

Code:

```
import requests as rq
headerw = {'api key here'}
url = 'https://api.f1234.com/v1/235e/2/1234'
fortnut_rank = rq.get(url,headers=headerw)

print(fortnut_rank)
```

Comment: Well what header should *contain* the API key? Authorization? You're trying to pass a set, which makes no sense.

Comment: the request header

Comment: That's not an answer. Headers are a *mapping*, they have keys and values, which is why Python clients represent them as dictionaries. Read the requests and API docs again more carefully to see what you need to do.

Comment: i'll give you the api doc, because my knowledge in this area is not very broad

Comment: https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api

Comment: You may have had more info when you generated the token. I'd guess it was something like `Authorization: Bearer {token}`, but you may have to talk to their support as it's not at all clear from that "self documenting" page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You you have to add the name of your api key so for example:

```
headerw = { 'ApiKey': 'xxxx-yyyy-zzz' }
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that they're just using a random custom header for the API key; do you *know* this is it, or are you just guessing?

Comment: The part "for example" indicates I don't know the exact headers Martin Mužík needs to send and that I give an example how to send custom headers.